# How to return True or False in a do expression - Haskell

Tags: haskell, io

I'm try to return True or False in this expression, but i'm getting this error, can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong? Thanks.

```
module Main (main) where
import System.IO (stdout, hSetBuffering, BufferMode(NoBuffering))

main::IO()
simOuNao::String -> Bool

main = do hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
      putStrLn "Guess Number v1.0"
      putStrLn "======================"

simOuNao frase = do putStrLn frase
                ans <- readLn
                if ans == 'y' || ans =='Y'
                  then return True
                  else return False
```

Error message:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘IO Bool’
• In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn frase
  In the expression:
    do { putStrLn frase;
         ans <- readLn;
         if ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y' then return True else return False }
  In an equation for ‘simOuNao’:
      simOuNao frase
        = do { putStrLn frase;
               ans <- readLn;
               if ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y' then return True else return False }
```

Failed, modules loaded: none.

Answer (score 5):

Once in `IO`, always in `IO` -- there is no escape.

```
simOuNao :: String -> IO Bool
```

Comment: Except for `unsafePerformIO :: IO a -> a`

Comment: @pat drawing attention to `unsafePerformIO` here is about as sensible as drawing attention to the possibility that you can access private elements of a C++ class through rogue pointer arithmetic, or another user's data through a side-channel attack on a CPU. Yeah, it turns out this can be done, but it's strictly undefined/implementation-specific behaviour (because `simOuNao` does have an observable side-effect) and nothing a beginner should even remotely consider.

Answer (score 2):

If your function does I/O, you have to declare it in the type by returning `IO Bool` instead.

```
simOuNao :: String -> IO Bool
simOuNao frase = do putStrLn frase
                    ans <- readLn
                    if ans == 'y' || ans =='Y'
                      then return True
                      else return False
```

The user of `simOuNao` will have to use something like

```
do ...
   b <- simOuNao frase
   ... -- here b is a Bool
```

and, of course, the type of this `do` expression will have to be `IO someType` once again.

Answer (score 2):

A [`do` expression](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14) is a way to write monadic code in sequence, using lines, `let` and `<-`. `True` and `False` are [`Bool`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Bool) constructors, and there is no [Monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Monad) instance for that. There are homomorphic types such as `Identity Bool` or `Maybe ()`.

Therefore, given the type declaration `simOuNao :: String -> Bool`, `simOuNao` cannot be defined as a `do` expression. Given that you're using `putStrLn` inside, it has to return something with the `IO` monad. So you've given conflicting goals. [`return`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:return) lifts values into a monadic type. So the `simOuNao` version you've written requires specifically the `IO` monad, and the type becomes `simOuNao :: String -> IO Bool`.

An additional complication is that you've used [`readLn`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:readLn). I suspect you meant to use [`getLine`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:getLine) and checking for strings starting with `'y'`, because as it is the user will need to enter `'y'` complete with quotes as `readLn` will expect a character literal.

It is also possible to use monads within a function that has a non-monadic type, including monads like `Identity`, `Maybe` and `State`, typically using some `run` function to extract the result. This isn't possible with the `IO` monad in particular, because its state is not deterministic (it represents the outside world, so all `IO` that is performed must be delegated from [`main`](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch5.html#x11-980005)).